# Incrementing an integer in a recursive method doesn't work(LinkedList)

Tags: java, recursion, increment

Basically I don't know why my integer `n` doesn't get higher.
Thanks for every answer!

```
    public int n;

    public int firstIndexOf(T val) {
    if (val == this.getValue()) {
        return n;
    } else {
        if (val != this.getValue() && this.next != null) {
            n++;
            return this.next.firstIndexOf(val);

        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: I assume this is Java? You should include such details in your question.

Comment: Because the element you're looking for is always found at the first node, or the list only has one element. NB 1. This is poor programming. Not thread-safe, for a start.  You should pass the new value of `n` as a parameter. 2. You don't need the first `!=` test. You're already in an `else` that says so. 3. You should compare values with `equals()`, not `==`.

Comment: okay thanks! problem is, is a part of a student task, im pretty new in java, thats why its problem bad. yeah your right, i can delete the first != thanks. im not allowed to add paramters. Do you have a solution maybe? otherwise i can make it with a non recursive method.
Edit: i think i got an idea, i make another method which copies val and has the parameter n. hope it works!

Comment: Make it non-recursive. Or else if you can add a second internal method that takes the parameter and does the recursing.

Answer (score 0):

The increment (n++) was in the wrong condition check:

```
    private int n = 0;

    public int firstIndexOf(int val) {
        if ( val == this.getValue() ) {
            return n+1; //This is were the increment should happen
        }
        else {
            if ( this.next != null ) {
                return this.next.firstIndexOf(val);
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also if you want to count all the elements in your linked list which have the same value as val, you can use this:

```
private int n = 0;

public int firstIndexOf(int val) {
    if ( val == this.getValue() ) {
        if ( this.next != null ) {
            return 1 + this.next.firstIndexOf(val);
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        if ( this.next != null ) {
            return this.next.firstIndexOf(val);

        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```